# Присвоить id элементу с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как с помощью jQuery найти все div с определенным классом и раздать им не повторяющиеся id

Answer (score 2):

js:

```
$("div.example").each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("class").attr("id", "div" + Math.random());
});
```

html:

```
<div class="example">
  Див1
</div>
<div class="example">
  Див2
</div>
```

В результате будет что-то вроде:

```
<div id="div0.37647746794184855">
    Див1
</div>
<div id="div0.6064644234577623">
    Див2
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxp6ahyw/)

Answer (score 2):

[функция attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) может принимать вторым параметром функцию, которая возвращает значение атрибута

```js
$('.block').attr('id', function(index) {
  return 'number' + (index + 1);
})
```

```css
#number1 {
  background: red;
}
#number2 {
  background: green;
}
#number3 {
  background: blue;
}
#number4 {
  background: yellow;
}
#number5 {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать порядковый номер для каждого последующего блока, то вот так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 1;                       // вводим порядковый номер в переменную
  $('.block').each(function(){     // перебираем все блоки по классу
    $(this).attr('id','number'+i); // присваиваем атрибут id
    i++;                           // увеличиваем порядковый номер в переменной на единицу
  })
})
```

```css
#number1 {background: red;}
#number2 {background: green;}
#number3 {background: blue;}
#number4 {background: yellow;}
#number5 {background: cyan;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
```

Comment: Тогда уж проще индекс брать из аргумегтов функции .each(function(i){})

Comment: Да, но я делал с учетом, что фактический вариант id в вопросе не указан, и, вероятнее, нужен не конкретно порядковый номер блока.  А в этом случае мой ответ нагляднее, и цифрами для id проще манипулировать.